# Equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $AB = 1$, $AC = 2$ and $m(\widehat{BAC}) = 30^\circ$. We build on the outside the equilateral triangles $ABM$ and $ACN$.

Let $D$, $E$ and $F$ be the midpoints of $AM$, $AN$ and $BC$.

a) Prove that triangle $DEF$ is equilateral.

b) Find $x$ and $y$ so that $\overrightarrow{MN} = x\overrightarrow{AB} + y\overrightarrow{AC}.$

For a) all I found is that $DE = \frac{\sqrt{5 + 2\sqrt{3}}}{2}$. For b) I have no idea how I should start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is not $\angle ACB=30°$?

Comment: @Aretino The problem clearly says it's about $\angle BAC$.

Comment: @GeorgeR. D you realize that triangle ABC is in fact a 30-60-90 triangle? AC =2 is the hypotenuse, right angle is at B

Comment: @imranfat sine rule doesn't valid in your case

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, I've checked the problem over and over and I copied it as it is on the paper.

Comment: I think one can prove it analytically using coordinate geometry

Comment: @AmanRajput I don't get it. AB=1, AC=2, BC=sqrt3, angle A=30, angle B = 90, angle C=60. It's a side-angle-side case, so no ambiguity.  What has the sine rule got to do with it?

Comment: In your case sin30 =√3/2 ...  It should be 1/2 ... Check out again.. don't waste your time

Comment: By applying the cosine rule you get $BC = \sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{3}}$. So $ABC$ is not a right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Let G be the midpoint of AC.

By midpoint theorem and some angle chasing, we have $\triangle DAE \cong \triangle FGE$.

Then, ED = EF and $\angle DEF = 60^0$ (from the fact that $\alpha = \alpha’$ and  using $\angle DEG$ as the middle man).

Comment: Nice! Your proof does not rely on $\angle BAC=60°$ or $AC=2AB$, which confirms that this is a very general result.

Comment: @Aretino I think you are right even if $\angle BAC$ is obtuse.

Comment: This figure is made by which software?

Comment: @AmanRajput Geogebra then PC Paint.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy using coordinates. Notice that $AB\perp AN$, so we can set $A=(0,0)$, $B=(0,1)$, $N=(2,0)$, $M=(-\sqrt3/2,1/2)$, $C=(1,\sqrt3)$.

It is then straightforward to find the coordinates of midpoints $D$, $E$, $F$ and check that $DE=EF=FD$, as well as finding $x$ and $y$ such that $\overrightarrow{MN} = x\overrightarrow{AB} + y\overrightarrow{AC}$.

It would be nice to prove that $DEF$ is equilateral by a purely geometrical argument. I haven't succeeded yet, but I noticed that this result has a more general validity: it is true for any value of $\angle BAC$, and for any length of $AB$ and $AC$.

Comment: I've added a geometrical proof.